# how to continue running an android app even when back button is pressed

Tags: android

I have made an android app that runs successfully. But when back button is pressed it stops. My app is supposed to work even when back button is pressed.

How to do this?
and where to place this piece of code?

Comment: You propably must implement a Service in your app! http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Your question is not absolutely clear...do You mean Your app should work in the background or it should not be closed at backbutton press?

Comment: Hello,not as a background proccess.The app must continue doing its job even when back button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a router in your app. See [ampersand-router](https://github.com/AmpersandJS/ampersand-router) for example. It will handle the "back" events of the browser.